# AVAudioPlayer crashes on play after upgrading to Xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, avaudioplayer

**Note awesome tip below from Stephen**: AVAudioPlayer does (for some reason!) **throw an exception** when it works properly; it's likely there is no crash at all.

---

I have so strange problem. After upgrading my project to Xcode5 the app crashes on sound play or prepareToPlay.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

NSLog(@"sound = nil? %d",snd == nil); // 0
NSLog(@"file = %@",snd.url.filePathURL.lastPathComponent); //test.mp3
NSLog(@"duration %f",snd.duration); //96.213333
```

after above lines:
1) snd is not nil - That's OK
2) snd.url.filePathURL.lastPathComponent returns right filename (test.mp3), - That's OK
3) duration is 96.213333 - That's OK

So the object exists and it has the sound loaded (duration time is ok)

then I do

```
[snd play]
```

and it crashes

if I do

```
[snd prepareToPlay]
```

it crashes too :(

Anyone has any idea why it crashes?

Comment: Is there any sort of crash information printed out in the output log/console in Xcode?

Comment: only some assembler lines

Comment: I was upgrading from Xcode3 and I do not use ARC

Comment: In the console window there is no information about the crash. In debug window I see the code is stopped on "AVAudioPlayer play" and there are some assembler lines as details.

Comment: enable exception breakpoints to see more detail on this. But beware that playing audio causes breakpoints to be hit, which stops the app 4 times, but isn't crashing (it just appears to)

Comment: THANKS!!!! :) I'm stupid ;) I've just had "add exceptions breakpoint" added in this project and It was just stopping 4 times as you said. So everything is OK with the code. Just I need to remember that sound causes exceptions even if there is no error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It is working, I have used in my code 
and it's already tested on Xcode 5 and works:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
NSError* error = nil;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
if(!audioPlayer)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
else
{ 
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: it's still crashes :( If I open new Xcode project my code works OK. It does not work on that one migrated from Xcode3

Comment: The problem was that I had added "exceptions breakpoint" to the project and on playing sound it's called 4 times even if there is no error. I thought it was crashing but it wasn't crashing but stopping 4 times. Thanks all for your help.